# Error while compiling and linking dll

Tags: c, gcc, dll, compilation

I am trying to compile a simple dll following the [cygwin tutorial](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html). I have been able to successfully do all but the last step. When I execute the command:

```
gcc -o myprog myprog.c -L./ -lmydll
```

I get an error saying that `hello()` is not declared in that scope. I followed the tutorial verbatim, yet I am still not able to compile the simple project and am lost as to why.

The code for the individual files are as follows:

(myprog.c)

```
int main(void){
    hello();
}
```

(mydll.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int hello(){
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Surely you should show us the code in myprog.c?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Updated, but I don't think there is a difference between that and the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

The example is working fine for me in my Cygwin

```
armathew@3NJ2VQ1 /cygdrive/d/userdata/armathew/Desktop/WWWW
$ ls
mydll.c  myprog.c

armathew@3NJ2VQ1 /cygdrive/d/userdata/armathew/Desktop/WWWW
$ gcc -c mydll.c

armathew@3NJ2VQ1 /cygdrive/d/userdata/armathew/Desktop/WWWW
$ gcc -shared -o mydll.dll mydll.o

armathew@3NJ2VQ1 /cygdrive/d/userdata/armathew/Desktop/WWWW
$ gcc -o myprog myprog.c -L./ -lmydll

armathew@3NJ2VQ1 /cygdrive/d/userdata/armathew/Desktop/WWWW
$ ./myprog.exe
Hello World!
```

What is the Cygwin version you are using? Mine is 1.7.5

```
armathew@3NJ2VQ1 /cygdrive/d/userdata/armathew/Desktop/WWWW
$ uname -r
1.7.5(0.225/5/3)
```

Answer (score 0):

well, the statement for linking library may be incorrect. 
It should be

> `-L<library path> -lyoulibrarymane`

as there is no "./" after the library path.
here is an example that I used, it may be helpful. the `-I/usr/local/include` is the header file path

> gcc -o hello-world helloopencv.c  -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib  -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc

Comment: What would the `-L` be if the `.dll` is in the same directory as the other files. There is only one folder of the `.c` and the `.dll`.

Comment: just delete "./" in your commend, if it's not work, than try the entire path of the library path. you can see your current working path by commend  'pwd'

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a declaration at the top of myprog.c:

```
int hello(void);
```

Or you could put this in a new mydll.h and #include that in myprog.c.

Comment: Why would this not be included in the example page? Is it just implied that you would do this?

Comment: If you compile with warnings disabled, the program will "work."  But no one should write code like that in 2014, or even 2004.  The tutorial code is simply not well written for modern times...like say the last 2.5 decades.